# Authenticating a denial by UK embassy

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, scams

10 years ago I used an agent to apply for UK visa, He said it was a group application.
I entered the UK embassy with him while he took the documents into an office while we waited outside, no biometrics was done. He came back after a week with the news that we were denied. And with a big black stamp at the back of my passport with the inscription UK2010.

Now my issue is I'm not sure if this guy actually applied or not, when did UK embassy started collecting biometrics and does UK2010 stamped at the back of the passport imply a denial?

I want to apply now but do not know what response to give.

Comment: You should probably add a photo of the stamp in your passport (with any personal info, including the passport number, blacked out, of course).

Comment: The passport expired and was retained when renewed.

Comment: This is really helpful I have a friend with same issue thanks very mush.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should request what information the UK Home Office holds on you, which will give you an indication as to whether the application you talk about was real or indeed a scam.

You can do this by submitting a "Subject Access Request", of which there are a few types depending on how much data you want.

The UK Government website has a good page on this: [Request personal information held in the borders, immigration and citizenship system](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so helpful. Will do just that.

Comment: As far as I can tell the UK Government is telling the truth [when it says](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/saru) that "all types of requests are free of charge."

Comment: @mlc ahh of course, it changed because of the GDPR - they used to charge a fee, but cant now.

Comment: I tried filling the form but I got stuck at the point where I had to provide a UK postal address. I couldn't continue as I have never been in the UK let alone having an address there, when I use my current address the system refuses to load the next page.  Will the option of sending a mail work instead?

Comment: @CaramelClothiers then work through your nearest embassy or consulate.

Comment: @Moo Well, for the next ten days anyway